# How to Configure Puppeteer to Properly Render External JS Pages? Works for Localhost URLs only

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, serverside-javascript

I am trying to configure server-side rendering for external Javascript Pages.
I am using Puppeteer for this purpose and when I provide any external URL (not localhost pages), Puppeteer fetches only the source code of the URL (what you may see in view-source mode of the requested page), without rendering the entire DOM.
When I try to SSR any localhost Javascript page URL (a page generated by the same node js server on my local host) - all works fine.

Please advise whether I am missing something or I need to try another approach.

I managed to configure puppeteer with all dependencies on my localhost as below:

Currently the 'html' variable returns only the source code of the fetched URL, I need to receive fully rendered DOM of the requested URL.

**Code in  server.js**

```js
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function ssr(url) {
  console.info('rendering the page in ssr mode');
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  try {
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw new Error('page.goto/waitForSelector timed out.');
  }

  const html = await page.content();
  await browser.close();
  return {html};
}

module.exports = ssr;
```

**Code in  app.js**

```js
var err = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var ssr = require('./ssr.js');

var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function(){ console.info('Server listening on port '); });

app.use('/index/', async(req, res) => {
  const { html } = await ssr(`www.example.com`);
  return res.send(html);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely, that you are not giving the page enough time to render the DOM contents. `{waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}` will only wait for the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event, not for any AJAX requests or DOM modifications.

Try to use `'networkidle0'` or `'load'` as `waitUntil` value of the [page.goto](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) function instead.

If that does not work, you have two options:

- Give the page a fixed amount of time to render the page by using [`await page.waitFor(1000)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args)
- Use [`await page.waitForSelector(/* ... */)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) to wait until a specific selector is loaded before calling `page.content()`. That way you can make sure, that the parts of the document you are interested in are loaded.

Comment: I actually tried using  the options described in official documentation by Google: 'networkidle0', 'networkidle2' and page.waitForSelector(...) before posting my public question, but the result was the same - only source html code of the URL (as if I checked the page in view-source mode) was returned by Puppeteer. All that works perfect only for pages that are generated by NodeJS on the localhost.
Don't even know what to check.

Comment: Hi Thomas! It doesn't unfortunately... Can it be because of the localhost (but there is no reason for that I guess). People from Chrome DEV Forum don;t reply. No, idea...

Comment: I get 404 reports in the terminal, for all linked scripts and images...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const html = 'what ever you selector is but since you want the html just type in "html"'; 

let gg = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
        let element = document.querySelector(sel);
        console.log ('got Boom');
        return element? element.innerHTML: null;
    }, html);


    console.log (gg);
```

Comment: Hi Rakah Habab!

Comment: Thank's for your reply! I am not an expert yet, so could you please clarify where exactly should I integrate the piece of code you provided?

Comment: Inside of your try statement

Comment: Thank's Rakah. I tried - again only source code of the requested page is returned in the terminal, the DOM build by JS is not rendered. Don't know what to do then...

Comment: I don't know what is the output you want. For instance do you want the header's text in this case it is "Example" OR do you want it like this "<h>Example<\h>"

Comment: I want in the output to get the HTML result of rendered Javascript. In other words to get fully rendered DOM.

Comment: it is very strange to me that if I try to render Javascript Page generated by the same nodejs server on Localhost, all javascript content gets properly rendered in HTML. Can't understand why Puppeteer can not do the same for other external URLs

Comment: well that's called a back-end and a front end for a reason the javascript is doing its job in the back-end and out-putting it for the user in a translated HTML file which is the front end. Puppeteer Looks at the front-end of the page (the visible part for the browser) and exploits it